# How to properly insert objects at an arbitrary position to an existing query set and update order sequentially?

Tags: python, django, list, django-views, django-queryset

I have two models `Book` and `Chapters` with a foreign key relation.

I'm trying to `INSERT` a `Chapter` in between an already existing chapters `QuerySet` that is ordered by `order` field, but having troubles in the following areas:

1. Maintaining the `order` in sequence after the `INSERT`.
2. Handling the slice operation when it goes negative (No negative index allowed for `QuerySet`).
3. Handling a non-sequential order.

**Example:**

Say I already have chapters 1 to 10. Now I need to add a *new chapter* between 1 and 2. So the *new chapter* should take the place of the current *chapter 2* in the database. So all the chapters after 2 and including itself should have an `order` of `order + 1` to make room for the new chapter.

**My code:**

**models.py**

```py
class Book(PubDateUpdDateMixin, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='authors')

class chapter(PubDateUpdDateMixin, models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chapters')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=30000)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

**views.py**

```py
class ChapterCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    model = Chapter
    slug_url_kwarg = 'book_slug'
    form_class = ChapterForm
    template_name_suffix = '-create'

    def get_object(self):
        return Book.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['book_slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChapterCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book'] = Book.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['book_slug'])
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        book = self.get_object()
        chapter = form.save(commit=False)
        chapter.book = book
        requested_order = form.cleaned_data['order']

        if requested_order == chapter.order:
            '''
            Reverse the queryset and slice it up to the requested order. 
            Add 1 to the chapter orders (chapter.order + 1).
            Save them to create a slot for the new chapter.
            '''
            chapters = course.chapters.order_by("-order")
            for l in chapters[:((len(chapters)+1)-requested_order)]:
                l.order += 1
                print(l.order)
                l.save()
        try:
            chapter.save()
        except IntegrityError as e:
            raise IntegrityError("Error: {}".format(e))

        return super(ChapterCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        book = self.get_object()
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            messages.info(self.request, 'You need to be logged in to edit a chapter.')
        elif book.author != self.request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(ChapterCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

This works for sequential ordering but fails for

1. When slice index turns negative.
2. Non-sequential ordering (when there are missing or deleted chapters in-between).

What am I missing? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Can you not just do `chapters = book.chapters.order_by("-order")` or am I missing something?

Comment: I missed it. ._. Thanks. I have changed my code and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ordering is sequential, you could use something like this:

```py
# Increment all chapter orders greater or equal to the requested order:
book.chapters.filter(order__gte=requested_order).update(order=F("order") + 1)

# Now just set the order directly on the object:
chapter.order = requested_order
chapter.save()
```

[Documentation for F expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model).

As it looks like this won't work for you, you may have to update the chapters one by one:

```py
for chapter_to_update in book.chapters.filter(
    order__gte=requested_order
).order_by('-order'):
    chapter_to_update.order += 1
    chapter_to_update.save()

chapter.order = requested_order
chapter.save()
```

This will be slower if you have a lot of chapters in a book.

Comment: I tried this approach, but I am getting Integrity error raised for the unique constraint I have for `(course_id, order)` fields. And no matter where I try to insert, it fails for `(1-13)`. The current orders are `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 21]`.

Comment: Which DB is this? Postgres?

Comment: The DB is MySQL.

Comment: I think this is going to be database-dependent, how the constraint is handled. And I'm not sure if MySQL checks before or during the change. I've edited the answer with something that should work, though it'll be slower than the original answer here.

Comment: You are right, this is slow. I am considering to switch to PostgreSQL soon. Thank you.

Comment: With postgres you will likely have the same issue by default, but you may be able to use a deferred unique constraint so the first solution works, but I'm not sure. Django can't do this for you though, you will need to make a SQL migration to create it.